flutter social_media_audio_recorder is showing error in IOS and working perfectly in android
I tried

social_media_recorder: ^1.1.13
social_media_audio_recorder: ^0.0.8

the second one is a perfect solution for android, but not working in IOS, because it generates .acc file instead of .aac which is not supported in IOS.
Anyone knows a perfect mp3 audio recorder as like social_media_audio_recorder?
social_media_audio_recorder
social_media_recorder
RecordButton(                                      
    color: AppColor.white,
    allTextColor: AppColor.black,
    controller: controller!,
    arrowColor: AppColor.black,
    size: AppIconSize.dm_48,
    recordButtonColor: AppColor.primary,
    recordBgColor: AppColor.chipGrey,
    radius: AppMargin.dm_100,
    releaseToSend: true,
    onRecordEnd: (String value) {
        setState(() {
        filepath = value;
        readOnly = false;
        });
        notifier.sendAudioMessage(filepath);
    },
    onRecordStart: () {
        setState(() {
        if (selectedMessageIndex != null) {
            selectedMessageIndex = null;
        }
        readOnly = true;
        });
    },
    onCancelRecord: () {
        setState(() {
        readOnly = false;
    });
    },
)

this is my button code.
